# How can I write the path in Python on a Windows?

Tags: python, windows, path

I'm currently trying to set up a webdriver, and I just realised the reason it's not working is because I can't get the path to work. Currently, I'm trying basic code:

```
file = "D:\\"
if os.path.exists(file):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

And the answer is "False". Now, I do have a D:/ drive on my computer.

I tried r"D:", "D:\", "D:/", basically everything I could find in other articles. Has anybody else ever encountered this?

Comment: What happens when you try 'C:\\'?

Comment: From the docs: "Note: os.path.exists() function may return False, if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path exists." - Maybe this is the problem? You can download Process Monitor and set a filter for path starting with `D:` and process name being `python3.exe` (or whatever the binary is called) to trace the access and why it fails

Answer (score 0):

```
file = "D:/"
```

Usually works, you could try a raw string literal if you are still having problems:

```
file = r'D:\'
```

You can also look into the excellent pathlib if you find yourself doing a lot of work with paths, such as constructing and joining. The documentation is available [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html)

Comment: fair enough! Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Could be a problem of your system? The python environment has access to your filesystem?
I tested if using `"D:/"` and it works.

```
file = "D:/"
if os.path.exists(file):
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Here a screenshot of the results:
[image]